# Bash Script to run MongoDB and Node Server in new terminal window

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a bash script to run mongoDB and a Node.js server.

Currently I tried implementing this thru Automater, however I was unable to accomplish this. I am now trying to accomplish the same task using a Bash Script.

Currently my shell scripts for MongoDB is located at

```
/User/Bacon/mongodb/bin/mongod
```

and

```
/User/Bacon/mongodb/bin/mongo
```

and my node.js server is located at

```
/User/Bacon/nodeapp/app.js
```

which is executed by typing in the terminal

```
node app.js
```

could someone explain to me how I should approach this? any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "screen". it's simpliest way.

You can try to run it  with "dtach" (available in breew) too.

```
su - mongo -c "dtach -n mongo /User/Bacon/mongodb/bin/mongod"
su - node -c "dtach -n nodejs node app.js"
```